# Implementation of class diagrams of java classes

Tags: java, uml, implementation, class-diagram

I wanted to know how i can design a uml class diagram or uml diagrams in General of These Java classes:

```
public class A{
 private A parent;
 private B[] b = new B[3];
 protected int i;
 private Vector<C> c; //container for objects of class C
 }

 public class B {

 }

 public class C {
 private A owner;
 public A getOwner() {return owner;}
 }
```

Maybe someone who has the Software can post an example how an class diagram in uml can look lie with These Java classes.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to show you how to create a UML diagram for the provided classes, or are you asking for possible software to create UML diagrams that will work for the provided classes?

Comment: The last one,because i wanna create it with Eclipse, found some plugins but my anti-Virus protection delete it automaticly. Wanted to know which Programm can bring the Java implementation to uml class diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?
[image]
**EDIT0:** and a simple object diagram sample
[image]

**Edit1:**
explanation:
in object diagram you should specify the value of each variable, here the `i=1990` is an example, it could be any number.

```
A a=new new A();
a.setI(1990);
```

as you see, there are two instances of class `A` named `a` and `a1`.

```
A a=new A();
A a1=new A();
```

The `a1` reference has no value for variable c, so it's `null`.
class `B` doesn't have anything(attribute) here.
in class `A`, the b variable is a array of class `B`, so `a` variable has two `B` references(`b0`,`b1`) and a `null` value.

```
B b0=new B();
B b1=new B();
a.setB(new B[]{b0,b1,null});
////
B b2=new B();
a1.setB(new B[]{null,null,b2});
```

and about the `:C` and `:Vector<C>`, why doesn't it have a name lie `a1` or `b0`? because there is no need for pointer(reference) for the class, so it doesn't need a pointer, in other word an object from `Vector<>` and two objects from `C` are created and passed to the host class `A`.

```
a.setC(new Vector<C>());
a.getC().put(new C(a));
a.getC().put(new C(a));
```

and about the `owner` in `C` class, assume that the owner is set during the object creation by constructor, or has set by a indirect reference (using `A.c`).

I hope I could give some hand dude.
Software: UMLet

Comment: Looks good,is it an direct convertion of the implementation or do you draw the single diagrams with some Tools?

Comment: How can i create an object diagram with the smallest possible (but not 0) item number,an object diagram with the smallest possible number of objects that contains an object of class A and a object diagram with the smallest possible number of objects that contains an object of class C. Because i dont understand how to create object diagrams with the class diagram you created.

Comment: Big thanks! Only for my understanding,can you explain why you say i=1990, i can only say int i and why is in a1 c=null? You split B to object diagrams of A and C,right? U split C to into 2 object diagrams of A and have 2 A class diagrams a and 1. Im a Little bit confused sry

Comment: Thanks buddy! I tried to create a class diagram of an example on stackoverflow with some painting tool. Would be nice if you can check if i am right and if not what i can do better.